# Error Correction possessive noun

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Wrong Sentence-All the candidates felt that this year's question paper was too easy.

Right Sentence-All the candidates felt that this year the question paper was too easy.

Why is "this year's question" in the sentence wrong???What are the rules to construct possessive sentences ?Is there any reference site where i can find out about possessive sentence?

Comment: You missed inversion on your question again. I suggest you try our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), for questions as basic as you have posed here.

Comment: Ohh sorry I need some practice on that I believe..But again what about the topic??Why is "this year's question" in the sentence wrong??Or is it both the sentences are right??

Comment: @ tchrist, choster, David M, Kristina Lopez, RyeɃreḁd I would really love to see those "commonly-available references" if you kindly point me out those commonly-available references discussing my question..Thank you..

Comment:          ’      

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, it's not wrong.

You need to say "candidates" (plural) in both sentences, but everything after "felt that..." is perfectly grammatical in both.

Comment: Also, the tenses of the verbs *felt* and *is* should probably match. Either they should be *feel* and *is*, or *felt* and *was*.

Comment: @PeterShor Usually. But "All the doctoral candidates felt that this year's proposed question paper is too easy; they want to stick it to the undergraduates."